# CUDA & VS2010 problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have scoured the internets looking for an answer to this one, but couldn't find any. I've installed the CUDA 3.2 SDK (and, just now, CUDA 4.0 RC) and everything seems to work fine after long hours of fooling around with include directories, NSight, and all the rest. Well, except this one thing: it keeps highlighting the `<<< >>>` operator as a mistake. Only on VS2010--not on VS2008.

On VS2010 I also get several warnings of the following sort:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xdebug(109): warning C4251: 'std::_String_val<_Ty,_Alloc>::_Alval' : class 'std::_DebugHeapAllocator<_Ty>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'std::_String_val<_Ty,_Alloc>'
```

**Update:** If I try and include an entry point in a `.cpp` file that calls a CUDA kernel, instead of writing `main()` in a `.cu` file as I was doing, the operator is actually flagged as an error, besides highlighting it! The same thing happens with VS2008.

Anyone know how this can be fixed?

**Update 2:** Here is the code. The `main.cpp` file:

```
#include "kernel.cu"

int main()
{
    doStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

and the `.cu` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cutil_inline.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define N 16

__global__ void MatAdd(float A[N][N], float B[N][N], float C[N][N])

{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

if (i < N && j < N)
    C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
}

int doStuff()
{
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(8, 8);
    dim3 numBlocks(N / threadsPerBlock.x, N / threadsPerBlock.y);

    float A[N][N], B[N][N], C[N][N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            A[i][j] = 0;
            B[i][j] = 0;
            C[i][j] = 0;
        }

    clock_t start = clock();
    MatAdd<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(A, B, C);
    clock_t end = clock();

    cout << "Took " << float(end - start) << "ms to work out." << endl;
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

**Update 3:** Alright, I was (idiotically) including the CUDA code in the `.cpp` file, so of course it couldn't compile. Now I have CUDA 4.0 up and running on VS2010, but I still get several warnings of the kind explained above.

Comment: So you have CUDA 4.0 RC working with VS 2010?

Comment: Partially, like I explain above. I followed the same procedure that should work with 3.2 and it compiles if I don't have a .cpp file in the solution. Otherwise I get the above problem. I'm to my wits' end, especially because the same thing happens with CUDA 3.2 (it's not a CUDA 4.0 problem).

Comment: So you're calling foo<<<...>>> from within main.cpp? I don't think this will (ever) work because only the NVCC compiler understands this syntax.

Comment: No, I'm calling doFoo() (which is in a .cu file) that calls foo<<< >>>().

Comment: I have this working with VS 2010 and CUDA 3.2 and NSight 1.51. If you comment out the <<< >>> line do you still see the compiler errors. I would expect to get intellisense warnings around <<< >>> but not compiler errors if it's in a .CU file.

Comment: Without the <<<>>> it compiles without errors. Let me try pasting the simple code here for a better look. Maybe I'm missing something (I'm new to CUDA).

Comment: If you only see these warnings with 4.0 then there may be issues with 4.0 on VS 2010. I didn't find anything to say that 4.0 is supported on 2010. Unfortunately NVidia's support for VS seems to lag behind their releases. If I can get my code working with the latest Thrust drop I'll try porting to 4.0 latest this weekend and maybe I can help more.

Comment: Yes, the warnings only happen with 4.0. I'll keep the answer open for the time being maybe someone else chimes in. Thanks for your help; your blog was invaluable (I came across it yesterday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this...

```
#include "kernel.cu"
```

Now you're asking the Visual Studio CPP compiler to compile the .CU file as though it was a header. You need to have a header file that declares doStuff() and include the header not the definition.

The following might be helpful.

http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/12/using-cudathrust-with-the-parallel-patterns-library/

http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/02/24/how-to-run-cuda-in-visual-studio-2010/

Typically I set this up as two projects. One project that compiles against the the 2008 CPP compiler for .CU and another that uses the 2010 compiler to get all the C++0x features.

The warnings your getting can be fixed by exporting the appropriate templates. Something like this but you'll have to write a specific one for each of the warning types.

```
#if defined(__CUDACC__)
#define DECLSPECIFIER  __declspec(dllexport)
#define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE

#else
#define DECLSPECIFIER  __declspec(dllimport)
#define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE extern
#endif

EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template class DECLSPECIFIER thrust::device_vector<unsigned long>;
```

See:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;168958 and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esew7y1w.aspx

**I've written a step-by-step guide to setting up VS 2010 and CUDA 4.0 here**

http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/03/using-cuda-and-thrust-with-visual-studio-2010/

BTW: A better way of timing CUDA code is with the event API.

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop; 
float time;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop); 
cudaEventRecord( start, 0 ); 
kernel<<<grid,threads>>> ( d_odata, d_idata, size_x, size_y, NUM_REPS); 
cudaEventRecord( stop, 0 ); 
cudaEventSynchronize( stop ); 
cudaEventElapsedTime( &time, start, stop );
cudaEventDestroy( start );
cudaEventDestroy( stop );
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd gotten that far just a minute before you posted the correct answer apparently (see below)! Now it compiles and all that remains are the numerous warnings like this: `Warning 2 warning C4251: 'std::_Locinfo::_Days' : class 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'std::_Locinfo' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xlocinfo 193`

Comment: @ade: in your blog post you refer to cuda sdk 3.2. i downloaded cuda sdk 4.0 today and it seems that vs2010 support is still not really provided, although nvidia claims to have it :( . have you tried cuda sdk 4.0 already in the meantime?

Comment: okay - i just found your blog post http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/06/cuda-4-0-and-vs-2010-samples-updated-for-4-0-release/ . i will try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I was including the `.cu` file directly. Of course, that's pretty much including the CUDA code in the `.cpp` file, and hence the error!

Comment: Yes. See the blog posts above for getting CUDA going on VS 2010. If you managed to get the 4.0 RC working with Parallel NSight let everyone know.